# Как делать параллельные http запросы в php?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom, parallelstream

С помощью simple_html_dom делаю 15 http запросов в цикле.
По очередность запросов занимает много времени.
Есть ли простой способ параллельно делать эти запросы?

Comment: разве что запустить 15 скриптов параллельно.

Comment: не подойдет, url's образуются в процессе, мне в принципе нужен что-то чтобы запустило бы каждый запрос отдельными процессами...

Comment: Может multicurl ?

Comment: К сожалению не смог найти и понять нормальный и понятный для себя пример, если кто сможет помочь примером, буду благодарен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Самый распространенный метод - использовать сервис сообщений [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/). В этом случае Вам нужно будет сразу отдавать какой-нибудь ответ. Но при этом реальный ответ будет, только после выполнения очереди. То есть основная идея возложить сложные операции не на php, а на сторонний сервис, который будет выполнять скрипты асинхронно, в очереди и при этом "освободить" php для других операций. Это самый идеальный вариант, но и достаточно сложный.
2. Как написал @Эдуард, использовать [curl_multi_init](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-multi-init.php).

> Позволяет асинхронную обработку множества cURL-дескрипторов.

Схема простая: инициализируем мультикурл и инициализируем ресурсы, выполяем запросы и получаем данные, закрываем все дескрипторы

```
// 1 инициализируем мультикурл и инициализируем ресурсы

$mh = curl_multi_init(); // инициализируем мультикурл

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $chs[] = ( $ch = curl_init() ); // создаем массив ресурсов курл
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // Устанавливает урл
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // выключаем заголовки если нужно
    ... // устанавливаем другие опции по-необходимости (например таймаут запроса, заголовки, проверка верификации ...)

    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);
}


//2. выполяем запросы и получаем данные

$status = null;

do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $status); // выполняем запросы в цикле

    $info = curl_multi_info_read($mh); // получаем информацию о текущих операциях
    $ch = $info['handle'];
    if (is_array($info)) {
          $content = curl_multi_getcontent($ch); // получаем содержимое
      }                
    } 
    while ($status == CURLM_OK);


// 3 закрываем все дескрипторы 

foreach ($chs as $ch) {
     curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch);
     curl_close($ch);
}
curl_multi_close($mh); // закрываем мультикурл
```

Comment: @Амирхон не понял вопрос

Comment: оказывается не до конца текст вставился, вопрос был в том, как вытащить из <div class="a"> <h1>info</h1> <div>    - info, но ответ нашел я, спасибо